# Regular Expression Split and match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning how to use regular expressions and am a bit confused by something hopefully some one can clarify, if I use the following string and expression I get the expected results with match but the exact opposite if I use split. Beating my head against the wall I don't understand why?

```
var a = "212,0,,456,,0,67889";
var patt = /,\d{1,5},/gmi;

pos=a.match(patt);
alert(pos);// returns ,0, ,456, and ,0,

pos=a.split(patt);
alert(pos); //returns 212, and ,67889
```

Comment: What are you expecting split to return?

Comment: I'm expecting an array with the same results that I would get from the match(), the regular expression remains the same just the method of searching has changed

Comment: Match and split do completely different things, though. Split doesn't return what the regex pattern matches--it splits the string on the regex you provide. You can use either method, but your pattern will need to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split means, look for a match of the pattern on the string and split that string every time you see a match. Also Remove each match you find.

This link has some good examples:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php

"~ a delimiter is used by the split function as a way of breaking up the string. Every time it sees the delimiter we specified, it will create a new element in an array. The first argument of the split function is the delimiter." (The delimiter is the pattern)

**Example one:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var myString = "123456789";

    var mySplitResult = myString.split("5");

    document.write("The first element is " + mySplitResult[0]); 
    document.write("<br /> The second element is  " + mySplitResult[1]); 
    </script>
```

**Output:**

```
The first element is 1234
The second element is 6789
```

"Make sure you realize that because we chose the 5 to be our delimiter, it is not in our result. This is because the delimiter is removed from the string and the remaining characters are separated by the chasm of space that the 5 used to occupy."

**Example Two:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myString = "zero one two three four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    document.write("<br /> Element " + i + " = " + mySplitResult[i]); 
}
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
Element 0 = zero
Element 1 = one
Element 2 = two
Element 3 = three
Element 4 = four
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes complete sense now. I tried giving the other answer a plus rating but couldn't because it says I don't have enough points...

Thanks to everyone for the help....

Comment: I am glad I could help! Choose an answer if they helped you though

Comment: lol thanks I was wondering why it wouldn't accept the others lol

Answer (score 1):

Consecutive splits are ignored, so you are just getting the two strings that don't match the regex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but what would need to be done in order to get the proper results with the split then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split or match to achieve the same, but you need different regex. For instance, you can use for match:

```
\d+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD2zN5/1)**

Code

```
var re = /\d+/g; 
var str = '212,0,,456,,0,67889';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Or you can use this regex to split:

```
,+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD2zN5/2)**